# Bootstrap 4: Flexbox Image on the left and text on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve this image below in bootstrap either thru column or flexbox:

[image]

Basically there must be a 965 x 678px image on the left and there are text floating on the right which if you check the fiddle below it is not function as it should be.

I tried to use Flexbox but its not working.

Here's my HTML:

```
<section id="golf">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <div class="menu-image">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/975x678" class="img-fluid" alt="menu image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-text">
                        <h2 class="main-title text-left">Golf Ter</h2>
                        <hr class="hr-style-left" />
                        <div class="menu-content d-flex space-between">
                            <p class="menu-name">GOlfy</p>
                            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="menu-content d-flex space-between">
                            <p class="menu-name">GOlfy</p>
                            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu-content d-flex space-between">
                            <p class="menu-name">GOlfy</p>
                            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu-content d-flex space-between">
                            <p class="menu-name">Kimbap</p>
                            <p class="menu-price">P200.00</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.menu-container{
  width: 100%;
}


.menu-content{
   margin-top: 1.5rem;
   width: 50%;
}

.menu-text{
    padding: 90px;
    width: 50%;
}

p.menu-name{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #191919;
    font-weight: bold;

}

p.menu-price{
    margin-left: 9rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #191919;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

This must be responsive w/c means when you resize the screen the image and the text must be still on the same position and will stack next to each other on mobile device screen.

Here's the jsfiddle so you can see the actual code: https://jsfiddle.net/L23zqn5x/1/

Comment: What exactly is your expected output behavior? The image resizes when you increase/decrease the size of the screen. What behavior do you need?

Comment: Check the jsfiddle and look at the image above, they are not the same. I need the image to sit on the left and the text on the right exactly as the image does and when you resize the screen it must be responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use your own CSS when bootstrap has provided you with the classes to achieve the desired layout.

In the code snippet below, i have removed unnecessary CSS and used bootstrap's grid layout along with flex utility classes to achieve the desired layout.

```css
#golf {
  border-top: 3px solid green;
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}

p.menu-name,
p.menu-price {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="golf">
  <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md">
        <div class="menu-image h-100 d-flex align-items-start">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/975x678" class="img-fluid" alt="menu image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md">
        <div class="menu-text flex-grow-1 py-4 px-5">
          <h2 class="main-title text-left">Golf Ter</h2>
          <hr class="hr-style-left" />
          <div class="menu-content d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p class="menu-name text-uppercase font-weight-bold">GOlfy</p>
            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
          </div>

          <div class="menu-content d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p class="menu-name text-uppercase font-weight-bold">GOlfy</p>
            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
          </div>

          <div class="menu-content d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p class="menu-name text-uppercase font-weight-bold">GOlfy</p>
            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
          </div>

          <div class="menu-content d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p class="menu-name text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Kimbap</p>
            <p class="menu-price">$200.00</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: how to preserve the aspect ration of the image here: https://prnt.sc/trpz1y
it must be consistent and occupy the whole left side

Comment: You miss the point on the image part. The image should expand the whole spaces on the left like this: https://prnt.sc/trqbrb

Comment: Just change `.container` class to `.fluid-container`. This will remove the gutter on the sides. See the updated code snippet.

Comment: how can I control the image from resizing and having a space at the top and botton on big screens?  See screenshot: https://prnt.sc/trqkup

Comment: Change class `align-items-center` to `align-items-start` on `.menu-image` element.

Comment: I tried but there is still the space the at the bottom I need it fill the whole container of the left side.

Comment: If you stretch the image, it will loose its aspect ratio